# System.InvalidProgramException when trying to run Powershell commands in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have ran a debug stepping through the program and it crashes at the following line

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
```

It gives the following error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred in     PrimarySMTP_Fix.exe

Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

This is my first time working with Power Shell through C# and I'm having trouble getting some simple code execution. The point of the project is to automate a simple fix for a common issue with our company's exchange server.

The complete code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;


namespace PrimarySMTP_Fix
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //Variable Declarations
    string userName = "";
    string confirmUser = "";
    string primarySMTP = "";
    string confirmSMTP = "";


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

        runspace.Close();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        userName = adUser.Text;
        confirmUser = confirmAD.Text;
        primarySMTP = mail.Text;
        confirmSMTP = confirmMail.Text;

        outPut.Text = RunScript(userName);


    }
}
}
```

The above is just setup to test. For now it's taking just the username information and running it directly as a command. If I can get that to work and output information then I can re-write it to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around for a while I found that I needed to reinstall the Windows Management Framework to get it to work. Figured that out when I put the debug build on the server and ran the test there and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, fixed also my problem.